# Call a JavaScript function when an element is fully loaded

Tags: jquery, html, wicket

I have on a ModalWindow (from wicket extensions) the following code (in html file):

```
<wicket:head>
<script src="static/js/scroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
          ffscroll('.scroller2');
    });
</script>
</wicket:head>

<wicket:panel>
<div wicket:id="scroller2" id="scroller2" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; height: 240px" class="scroller2 YYYY ZZZZ">
  .... 
</div>
</wicket:panel>
```

and scroll.js

```
function ffscroll(id) {
        $(id).scroll(function () { 
            alert(id);
        });
    };
```

If I use a simple page this code works fine: every time I scroll I receive an alert.

But in ModalWindow I saw that the JavaScript code is executed before the modal window is displayed, so I suppose I need to call *ffscroll('.scroller2');* after the modal window is displayed, but I don't know how to do this.

A strange thing is that in firebug my script is displayed like this:

```
function () {
  ffscroll(".scroller2");
  alert("aaadssd");
}
```

" instead of '.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's good practice to put your JS in a resource file, then add it in which ever component you are using:

For globally define files:

```
add(JavascriptPackageResource.getHeaderContribution("js/general.js"));
```

For package relative:

```
add(new JavascriptResourceReference(MyPage.class, "MyPage.js"));
```

Since `ModalWindow` are loaded using ajax its required JavaScript source files will be downloaded and run on the ajax callback.

Or if you look at `ModalWindow.show(final AjaxRequestTarget target)` it adds JavaScript to the `AjaxRequestTarget` using `target.appendJavascript()`, you could override the `show` method to add the extra JavaScript:

```
...
@Override
public void show(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    super.show(target);
    target.appendJavascript("ffscroll('.scroller2');");
}
```

Then when the Ajax callback is called on the client browser this JavaScript will get run.

Hope that helps